# Filamentphp displaying one-to-many relationship in repeater select list not displaying data

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am building a filament repeater in a form. The form is to create an event where I assign users to the event. Many users can get assigned to events but they can also get assigned to many stands and levels as well. I have created a pivot model 'event_user' and the database table has the following columns:

id
event_id
stand_id
level_id
user_id

**Event User Pivot Model**

```
class EventUser extends Pivot
{
    public function event(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function stand()public function event_users(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventUser::class);
    }

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(EventUser::class);
    }
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stand::class);
    }

    public function level()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Level::class);
    }
}
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function event_users(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventUser::class);
    }

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(EventUser::class);
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function events(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }
}
```

The repeater form code is as follows:

```
TableRepeater::make('event_users')
                        ->relationship()
                        ->hideLabels()
                        ->schema([
                            Select::make('stand_id')
                                ->relationship('stand', 'name')
                                ->required()
                                ->label('Stand'),
                            Select::make('level_id')
                                ->relationship('level', 'name')
                                ->required()
                                ->label('Level'),
                            Select::make('user_id')
                                ->relationship('user', 'name')
                                ->label('Runners')
                                ->required()
                                ->multiple()
                                ->searchable(),



                        ])
```

When editing the form, the stand and level gets populated but the users field does not get populated at all

The database table data is as follows:

| id | event_id | stand_id | level_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 11 |

[image]

What I am expecting si the user select list to be populated with the selected names